# Fish Alias Not Saving Variable Calls

Tags: shell, alias, fish

I currently use the command below to check a csv file for duplicates and this works just fine running it in the Fish shell. So now I'd like to save it as an alias but it strips away the variables from print.

Command used.

```bash
awk -F ',' '{print $2 $3}' Data.csv | sort -n | uniq -cd | sort -n
```

alias returned

```
awk -F ',' '{print }' Data.csv | sort -n | uniq -cd | sort -n
```

Obviously, this is not going to check any columns in the file. So how can variable calls be stored in alias functions.

I ran the command

```
alias --save data="awk -F ',' '{print $2 $3}' Data.csv | sort -n | uniq -cd | sort -n"
```

Comment: In non-fish shells, I would have the same "don't use an alias for this at all -- use a function instead" advice you're getting from faho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fish, like other shells, expands variables in double-quotes.

```
alias --save data="awk -F ',' '{print $2 $3}' Data.csv | sort -n | uniq -cd | sort -n"
```

That `"awk`? That's double-quoting. That's also why the `$2` and `$3` will be colored like variables in an interactive fish session.

So it runs the `alias`, but before it does that it replaces the values of `$2` and `$3`, and since they aren't set it just ends up as nothing, so you get `print`  .

What you need is to either escape the `$` of the variable expansion, or to use single-quoting, in which case you need to escape the `'` quotes for the awk-call.

So either

```
alias --save data='awk -F \',\' \'{print $2 $3}\' Data.csv | sort -n | uniq -cd | sort -n'
```

or

```
alias --save data="awk -F ',' '{print \$2 \$3}' Data.csv | sort -n | uniq -cd | sort -n"
```

Honestly, just do yourself a favor and make it a normal function:

```
function data
    awk -F ',' '{print $2 $3}' Data.csv | sort -n | uniq -cd | sort -n
end
```

and then run `funcsave data`. This not only simplifies quoting but also allows you to put `$argv` wherever you want, so you could for example replace that `Data.csv` with `$argv` and run it as `data Data.csv` or `data Data-2.csv` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is really helpful. Not only did you answer my question, but helped me understand how fish (and other shells in general) work! I've just been using BASH so long, it's hard to move over sometimes.